# getting distinct value with all column sqlserver

Tags: sql

```
select 
    distinct TagName as new, *,(REPLACE(TagName,' ','-')) as SeoProduct_Name 
from 
    dbo.tbl_Image_Master 
        inner join  
    dbo.tbl_size 
        on tbl_size.Size_Id=tbl_Image_Master.Size_Id 
        inner join 
    tbl_category 
        on tbl_category.Cat_Id = tbl_Image_Master.Cat_Id
```

I want to select distinct tag name with all column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE TAGNAME IN (
SELECT DISTINCT TAGNAME FROM TBL)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TAGNAME ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ROWNUM FROM TBL WHERE TAGNAME) 
WHERE ROWNUM =1
```

Hope it solves the Purpose !!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all columns from a table in a query you can use this syntax :

```
TableName.*
```

Example :

```
Select Table1.Col1, Table1.* from Table1;
```

I would post what your query becomes, but I am not sure what table you want all columns from.

Comment: thanks for reply.. i want show all column from table  but column tagname have repeat value that show only distinct value, no repeat same value

Comment: i use this query: SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE TAGNAME IN ( SELECT DISTINCT TAGNAME FROM TBL) but it show all  column but tagname show repeat value

Comment: You have to post the structure of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

In the distinct query you cannot select all the columns you need because if you do so you are going to get multiple values that you don't need.

So what you can do is to use you query inside another query, as for example

```
SELECT TagName AS new, *,(REPLACE(TagName,' ','-')) AS SeoProduct_Name,
<other_colums_you_need>
FROM <table>
WHERE ItemID IN (
                  SELECT DISTINCT TagName <replaceWithSomeID>
                    FROM dbo.tbl_Image_Master 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_size 
                    ON tbl_size.Size_Id=tbl_Image_Master.Size_Id 
                    INNER JOIN tbl_category 
                    ON tbl_category.Cat_Id = tbl_Image_Master.Cat_Id
                    )
```

Remember that the values that you require (rows) need to have an unique identifier or ID column, so make sure to return in the subquery that unique ID of the values you need. So you are only going to get the info you require.